# What's the Insert/Update Speed like on an AWS RDS Small?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Are there any benchmarks for the insert/update speed on an RDS small instance?

I'm looking for just ballpark numbers.

Can it perform a few hundred inserts/updates per second?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the information found within the RDS docs is extremely thorough. Should you require any specifics, I'm sure you could email Amazon and they'd be happy to provide you with the latest data on your geographic location.

Saying that, if all you want are some quick-and-dirty numbers, see: http://www.johngaltsystems.com/blog/amazon-web-serices-rds-benchmark-results/

You may gain better results running mysql bench on your own instance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm having a little difficulty understanding what the numbers mean. On the bottom of the page for update_with_key, does it says it took 3313 seconds to perform 300000 updates with key?

Comment: Also, any idea what instance type the article is covering?